# Use a variable that contains a list of arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, arguments

I'm trying to write a script that rebuild current installed version of nginx on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I don't understand why it fails when I add the `configure` command options :

```
#!/bin/bash

NGINX_VERSION=$(nginx -v 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9.]*')
NGINX_BUILD_ARGS=$(nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=configure arguments: )--.*$')

echo ${NGINX_BUILD_ARGS[@]}
# output:
# --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-FIJPpj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module

wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xvzf nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz
rm nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}
./configure ${NGINX_BUILD_ARGS}

# it fails with "invalid option -O2"
```

If I try to launch the command by myself in the folder :

```
./configure --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-FIJPpj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

I got a success...

Is there a way to use `${NGINX_BUILD_ARGS}` as a list of arguments ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**

Tried with quotes :

```
./configure "${NGINX_BUILD_ARGS}"
```

But arguments seems to be bad parsed...

**EDIT 2**

It works with an eval :

```
eval "./configure ${NGINX_BUILD_ARGS}"
```

Isn't it unsafe ? No way to create an array from build args variable ?

Comment: @Cyrus Yep I can see it escapes quotes like `'--with-cc-opt='\''-g -O2` but how avoid that ?

Comment: Take a look at [Bash FAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).